# Throw custom exception from catch-exception-strategy

Tags: java, exception, mule

Is it possible to throw our own custom exception from `catch-exception-strategy` or any other exception strategies.

I tried like below:

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
  <scripting:component doc:name="throw-custom-exception">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      <![CDATA[throw new org.mycompany.mule.CustomException()]]>
    </scripting:script>
   </scripting:component> 
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

but ended up with the error:

`org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: Failed to dispatch message to error queue after it failed to process`

Can anyone solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the

```
<scripting:component doc:name="throw-custom-exception">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      <![CDATA[throw new org.mycompany.mule.CustomException()]]>
    </scripting:script>
   </scripting:component>
```

outside `catch-exception-strategy` and try...

Comment: I know, it works fine if I put the scripting component outside `catch-exception-strategy`. What I actually need is upon catching an exception inside `catch-exception-strategy`, I just need to wrap the cause and re-throw my custom exception. Is it possible?

Comment: Indeed that seems impossible. I don't think above is a solution for this question.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the re-throwing of an exception.